# scope using a try catch and linq

Tags: c#, linq

I really have tried with this but just can't quite get it to work.
I have a bunch of files that I am using Linq to parse, but some of them have a field that the others do not have.  There is no way of knowing by the file name.

Here is the code that runs against the file:

```
var update = from d in document.Descendants("Update")
                         select new
                         {
                             OrderNumber = d.Element("OrderNumber").Value,
                             StopID = d.Element("StopID").Value,
                             TransmissionTime = d.Element("TransmissionTime").Value,
                             EventTime = d.Element("PODTime").Value,
                             recordCreated = d.Element("EventTime").Value,
                             EventType = d.Element("EventType").Value,
                             EventCode = d.Element("EventCode").Value,
                             POD = d.Element("POD").Value,
                             Note = d.Element("Note").Value,
                             CustomerID = d.Element("CustomerID").Value,
                             OrderID = d.Element("OrderID").Value,
                             StopRef = d.Element("StopRef").Value,
                             PieceCount = d.Element("PieceCount").Value,
                             TotalWeight = d.Element("TotalWeight").Value,
                             DriverID = d.Element("DriverID").Value
                         };
```

Now the problem is that some of them do not have the Element("PODTime") so I need a differnet linq query.  I was just going to do a try/catch and if it fails run the other one (cludgy I know).
But obviously as soon as I put update in a try/catch I can no longer access it outside of it.

Normally I would just define it before the try/catch - but I can't get that to work here.

I have tried:

```
System.Linq.Enumerable update = new System.Linq.Enumerable();
```

But that is not right.  If somebody could point me the right direction I would apprecaite it.

Solution: 
Using Sledgehammers nudge combined with a Let:

```
var update = from d in document.Descendants("Update")
                             let elName = d.Element("PODTime")
                             select new
                             {
                                 OrderNumber = d.Element("OrderNumber").Value,
                                 StopID = d.Element("StopID").Value,
                                 TransmissionTime = d.Element("TransmissionTime").Value,
                                 EventTime = (elName != null) ? elName.Value : string.Empty,
```

Comment: Well you're essentially going to be building two separate anonymous objects if you have two different queries if a field doesn't exist. Why not select null or empty string if the field does not exist?

Comment: do you have to use Linq for this? The deserialization would be much easier with static types

Comment: Collin - I am not sure how to do that if a element is not there?  That would probably solve the problem for me. I have not come across this need before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the new ?. operator for this:

```
d.Element("CustomerID")?.Value
```

Or if you can't use the newest C#, you can write a "Safe" method to wrap all your calls in:

```
string SafeGetValue(XElement elem)
{
  if (elem == null)
    return null;

  return elem.Value;
}
```

Comment: I cannot find any informatoin on what the ? operator does or how to use it.  What is it called, google is failing me!

Comment: @MostlyLucid Search for null conditional operators. I showed you how to use it. It lets you chain your calls without checking for nulls everywhere.

Comment: the null conditional operater ?. is an new feature in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: Here is a helpful description of this operator:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx

Comment: `return elem == null ? null : elem.Value`